# How safe is it to use OpenID to log in to a site?

Tags: discussion, openid

Is Super User limiting the practical use of the site by mandating the use of
OpenID to log in?
I could not ask this question on meta without the use of an OpenID.
If I create an OpenID using Yahoo, I am told by Yahoo that I must log
off Super User and Yahoo in order to sign off?
So, if I have an OpenID and I keep Super User's cookie
do I never have to sign in to Super User?

Comment: What? Rephrase please, I can't understand you.

Comment: Rephrase this so it's not completely about SO/SU etc. Otherwise it'll get moved to meta.

Comment: I think what the user is asking is whether it is safe to use OpenID in general and whether or not anyone has any insight into how it works and whether giving your information to one place (OpenID) is essentially giving up your whole "profile" away to all the sites that use OpenID.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem. I'm logged into all four sites using the same OpenID (from [myopenid.com](http://myopenid.com)) at the same time without having to log out of any of them.

It might be an issue with Yahoo's implementation of OpenID.